# PyAnnote Giving [Errno -9981] Input overflowed

Tags: python, voice

I have 2 files that require me to record a voice sample. I'm trying to install a [voice authentication library](https://github.com/MohamadMerchant/Voice-Authentication-and-Face-Recognition). I have successfully recorded voice samples to add my voice to the database. However, when I try to record a voice sample to recognise my voice, I get `OSError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed`. The code to record is the same between the two files.

`add_user.py` (running successfully)

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 44100
    CHUNK = 1024
    RECORD_SECONDS = 3
    
    source = "./voice_database/" + name
    
   
    os.mkdir(source)

    for i in range(3):
        audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

        if i == 0:
            j = 3
            while j>=0:
                time.sleep(1.0)
                os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
                print("Say your name in {} seconds".format(j))
                j-=1

        elif i ==1:
            time.sleep(2.0)
            print("Say your name one more time")
            time.sleep(0.8)
        
        else:
            time.sleep(2.0)
            print("Say your name one last time")
            time.sleep(0.8)

        # start Recording
        stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        print("recording...")
        frames = []

        for _ in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)

        # stop Recording
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()
```

`recognize.py` (raises error)

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 44100
    CHUNK = 1024
    RECORD_SECONDS = 4
    FILENAME = "./test.wav"

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
   
    # start Recording
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    time.sleep(2.0)
    print("recording...")
    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
    print("finished recording")


    # stop Recording
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()
```

I tried changing the parameter values but since the params are the same between the two files, I suspect that that is not the issue. I'm using a MacOS and have no Raspberry Pi attached to my project.